# How to keep the order of references in `bib` when convert it to `bbl` in LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an article with Latex template in which there is a `bbl` file, so I need to convert `bib` file to `bbl` file by

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

In the `bib` file

```
@article{RN108,
   author = {Bortey-Sam, Nesta and Nakayama, Shouta M. M. and Ikenaka, Yoshinori and Akoto, Osei and Baidoo, Elvis and Mizukawa, Hazuki and Ishizuka, Mayumi},
   title = {Health risk assessment of heavy metals and metalloid in drinking water from communities near gold mines in Tarkwa, Ghana},
   journal = {Environmental Monitoring and Assessment},
   volume = {187},
   number = {7},
   ISSN = {0167-6369},
   DOI = {10.1007/s10661-015-4630-3},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10661-015-4630-3},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN127,
   author = {Chen, Quanyuan and Yao, Yuan and Li, Xinying and Lu, Jun and Zhou, Juan and Huang, Zhaolu},
   title = {Comparison of heavy metal removals from aqueous solutions by chemical precipitation and characteristics of precipitates},
   journal = {Journal of Water Process Engineering},
   volume = {26},
   pages = {289-300},
   abstract = {Typical chemical precipitation methods using lime (Ca(OH)2), soda ash (Na2CO3) and sodium sulfide (Na2S) for removals of heavy metals (i.e. Zn (II), Cu (II) and Pb (II)) from aqueous solutions were compared by jar tests. A focus was especially given to particle size differences and chemical phase conversion of precipitates. A removal of 99.99% from aqueous solutions with three precipitants was achieved for copper and zinc at an initial concentration of 100 mg/L. And lead was efficiently removed (99.75%) by sodium sulfide. In contrast, the maximal lead removals with lime or soda ash precipitation were only 76.14% and 97.78%. The mean particle size of precipitates was in the range of 55 nm–45 μm, depending on properties of precipitants and heavy metal to precipitant ratios. The settling performance of the sludge derived from precipitation was dominated by particle size and Zeta-potential of precipitates. It was observed that ultra-fine copper sulfide particles resulted from the precipitation were around 55 nm and did not settle in 12 h due to electrostatic repulsion force between particles. The main compounds in the sludge obtained from precipitation were metal hydroxides and metal sulfides. However, spontaneous dehydration of metal hydroxide, oxidation of sulfide and atmospheric carbonation were identified by means of XRD and thermal analyses, which is invaluable to the disposal and utilization of the sludge.},
   keywords = {Heavy metal
Precipitation
Sludge characteristics
Particle size
Solid–liquid separation},
   ISSN = {2214-7144},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.jwpe.2018.11.003},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jwpe.2018.11.003},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN163,
   author = {De Jesus, Kevin Lawrence M. and Senoro, Delia B. and Dela Cruz, Jennifer C. and Chan, Eduardo B.},
   title = {Neuro-Particle Swarm Optimization Based In-Situ Prediction Model for Heavy Metals Concentration in Groundwater and Surface Water},
   journal = {Toxics},
   volume = {10},
   number = {2},
   pages = {95},
   ISSN = {2305-6304},
   DOI = {10.3390/toxics10020095},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.3390/toxics10020095},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN104,
   author = {Duggal, Vikas and Rani, Asha and Mehra, Rohit and Balaram, V.},
   title = {Risk assessment of metals from groundwater in northeast Rajasthan},
   journal = {Journal of the Geological Society of India},
   volume = {90},
   number = {1},
   pages = {77-84},
   ISSN = {0016-7622},
   DOI = {10.1007/s12594-017-0666-z},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12594-017-0666-z},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN96,
   author = {Egbueri, Johnbosco C.},
   title = {Assessment of the quality of groundwaters proximal to dumpsites in Awka and Nnewi metropolises: a comparative approach},
   journal = {International Journal of Energy and Water Resources},
   volume = {2},
   number = {1-4},
   pages = {33-48},
   ISSN = {2538-3604},
   DOI = {10.1007/s42108-018-0004-1},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s42108-018-0004-1},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN255,
   author = {Findik, Ö and Aras, S.},
   title = {Application of the metal pollution indices on surface waters for assessment of environmental risk: a case study for Damsa reservoir (Cappadocia, Türkiye)},
   journal = {International Journal of Environmental Science and Technology},
   ISSN = {1735-1472},
   DOI = {10.1007/s13762-022-04102-1},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13762-022-04102-1},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN229,
   author = {Long, Xiting and Liu, Fei and Zhou, Xin and Pi, Jing and Yin, Wei and Li, Fang and Huang, Shuping and Ma, Fang},
   title = {Estimation of spatial distribution and health risk by arsenic and heavy metals in shallow groundwater around Dongting Lake plain using GIS mapping},
   journal = {Chemosphere},
   volume = {269},
   pages = {128698},
   abstract = {Potable groundwater has become the primary water source for the local population because of the serious pollution of As and heavy metals in the surface water around the Dongting Lake Plain. A comprehensive research on the shallow groundwater was performed in this study via geographical information system (GIS) and geochemical method to evaluate groundwater quality and health risks of shallow groundwater in Dongting Lake Plain. Eighty-seven samples were collected and the content of As and twelve other heavy metals (e.g., Al, Fe, Zn, Cu, Mo, Ni, Mn, Co, Ba, Pb, Cd, and Cr) in the samples were detected by inductively coupled plasma–mass spectrum (ICP-MS) technology. The water pollution situation was assessed using heavy metal contents and evaluation indices, and human health risks were evaluated on the basis of both carcinogenic and noncarcinogenic aspects. Results showed that the shallow groundwater quality is moderately to heavily contaminated and should be considered in some areas of the Li and Xiangjiang River coasts. Several regions have the potential of carcinogenic risks induced by As and the groundwater in some regions may have the risk of Cr carcinogenesis in the wet season. These findings suggested that the potential harm caused by Fe, Zn, Mn, Cr, and As pollution of groundwater, especially As and Cr in wet season, must be considered. The spatio-temporal study on the groundwater quality evaluation may be beneficial to the protection and sustainable development of groundwater resources in Dongting Lake Plain.Summary: Although the overall noncarcinogenic health risk by metals in shallow groundwater of Dongting Lake is low, noncarcinogenic health risks caused by Fe, Zn, Mn, and As exist in some areas.},
   keywords = {Dongting lake floodplain
Shallow groundwater
Arsenic
Heavy metal
GIS-Mapping},
   ISSN = {0045-6535},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.chemosphere.2020.128698},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2020.128698},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN213,
   author = {Muthukumaran, Peraman and Suresh Babu, Palanisamy and Shyamalagowri, Shanmugasundaram and Kamaraj, Murugesan and Manikandan, Arumugam and Aravind, Jeyaseelan},
   title = {Nanotechnological approaches as a promising way for heavy metal mitigation in an aqueous system},
   journal = {Journal of Basic Microbiology},
   volume = {62},
   number = {3-4},
   pages = {376-394},
   note = {Times Cited: 1
Si
PALANISAMY, SURESH BABU/AAH-4523-2019; Shanmugasundaram, Shyamalagowri/; Kamaraj, Murugesan/; Aravind, J/O-9296-2015
PALANISAMY, SURESH BABU/0000-0001-9859-2208; Shanmugasundaram, Shyamalagowri/0000-0002-4273-1253; Kamaraj, Murugesan/0000-0002-0111-8524; Aravind, J/0000-0001-9699-2312
0
1
3
5
1521-4028},
   abstract = {The ever-rising environmental problems because of heavy metals emerging from anthropogenic activities pose an impending threat to all biota globally. Considering their persistence and possibility in biomagnification, they are prominent among pollutants. There has been an apparent shift of research interest in advancing cost-effective and competent technologies to mitigate environmental contaminants, specifically heavy metals. In the recent two decades, tailored nanomaterials (NMs), nanoparticles, and NM-based adsorbents have been emerging for removing heavy metal pollution on a sustainable scale, especially the green synthesis of these nanoproducts effective and nonhazardous means. Hence, this review explores the various avenues in nanotechnology, an attempt to gauge nanotechnological approaches to mitigate heavy metals in the aqueous system, especially emphasizing the recent trends and advancements. Inputs on remediating heavy metal in sustainable and environmentally benign aspects recommended future directions to compensate for the voids in this domain have been addressed.},
   ISSN = {0233-111X},
   DOI = {10.1002/jobm.202100365},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/jobm.202100365},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN230,
   author = {Satarug, Soisungwan},
   title = {Cadmium Sources and Toxicity},
   journal = {Toxics},
   volume = {7},
   number = {2},
   pages = {25},
   ISSN = {2305-6304},
   DOI = {10.3390/toxics7020025},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.3390/toxics7020025},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN95,
   author = {Tiwari, Ashwani Kumar and Singh, Abhay Kumar and Singh, Amit Kumar and Singh, M. P.},
   title = {Hydrogeochemical analysis and evaluation of surface water quality of Pratapgarh district, Uttar Pradesh, India},
   journal = {Applied Water Science},
   volume = {7},
   number = {4},
   pages = {1609-1623},
   ISSN = {2190-5487},
   DOI = {10.1007/s13201-015-0313-z},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13201-015-0313-z},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN226,
   author = {Zhang, Shengnan and Tian, Yimei and Guo, Hao and Liu, Ran and He, Nan and Li, Zhuang and Zhao, Weigao},
   title = {Study on the occurrence of typical heavy metals in drinking water and corrosion scales in a large community in northern China},
   journal = {Chemosphere},
   volume = {290},
   note = {Times Cited: 0
zhao, weigao/0000-0002-4955-1626
0
22
1879-1298},
   abstract = {Excessive heavy metal content in drinking water could lead to red water and acute and chronic diseases. A field study in combination with batch experiments using pipe scales of drinking water distribution systems (DWDS) in the study area, was used to determine the content distribution and migration of As, Cd, Cr, Mn, Pb, and V in DWDS. In the field study, As, Cd, Cr, Pb, and V contents in pipe scales and drinking water were extremely low and did not exceed the Chinese drinking water standards. However, Mn concentrations at the end of the DWDS with aged and corrosive pipes were relatively high, which presented a risk of excessive release. The batch experiment showed that As in pipe scales would not be released into water under static immersion conditions; however, pipe scales would release excessive Cd, Cr, Mn, Pb, and V in the initial reaction stage, and the heavy metal contents released by tubercle scales in the initial release stage were at least twice as much as those released by loose scales. The mass percentage of four metals (excluding Cd and Pb) released from pipe scales was extremely low. The field study and batch experiment data both suggested a strong correlation between Cr and V released into the water, indicating a synergistic effect. There were differences in heavy metals released in the field research and the batch experiment. The amount of Cd, Cr, Pb, and V released were not consistent with its proportion in pipe scales. As release did not occur under static conditions, but may be promoted by the water flow in the actual network. The effect of water flow on heavy metal release in DWDS should be considered.},
   ISSN = {0045-6535},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.chemosphere.2021.133145},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2021.133145},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

After converting, I see in the `bbl` file the reference order is not as that in the `bib` file. But in the template, I need the original order. So is there a way to keep the order in `bbl` file like that in `bib` file?

Comment: If you use the `plain` style the references are ordered alphabetically. Try with `unsrt`, for instance.

Comment: May you give me the code? I don't know where and how to insert `unsrt`? @Fran

Comment: Just change "plain" by "unsrt" in the 4th line of your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your bibliographic entries contain fields such as `url`, `issn`, and `doi`, I suggest you load the `natbib` package and employ the `unsrtnat` bibliography style. (The much older `plain`, `abbrv§, and` unsrt`bibliography styles have been around -- more or less unchanged -- since before the invention of the WWW. Maybe unsurprisingly, these ancient styles have not been programmed to do anything with fields such as`url`and`doi`.)

As its name suggests, the `unsrtnat` bib style does not perform any sorting of its own. This implies that the entries will displayed according to the ordering that applies when they're first encountered. Since they're "encountered" via a `\nocite{*}` instruction, the sorting order will correspond to how the entries are sorted in the bib file itself. That's exactly what you want, isn't it?

The following screenshot shows the 11th and final entry of the resulting formatted bibliography. Observe that I had to change the word `China` in the `title` field to `{China}`, i.e., encase it in curly braces, to inform BibTeX that this word mustn't be converted to all-lowercase. (By default, the `plainnat` and `unsrtnat` bib styles -- and many other bib styles too -- employ "sentence style", which means that all words except the first word of each sentence are converted to lowercase.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@article{RN108,
   author = {Bortey-Sam, Nesta and Nakayama, Shouta M. M. and Ikenaka, Yoshinori and Akoto, Osei and Baidoo, Elvis and Mizukawa, Hazuki and Ishizuka, Mayumi},
   title = {Health risk assessment of heavy metals and metalloid in drinking water from communities near gold mines in Tarkwa, Ghana},
   journal = {Environmental Monitoring and Assessment},
   volume = {187},
   number = {7},
   ISSN = {0167-6369},
   DOI = {10.1007/s10661-015-4630-3},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10661-015-4630-3},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN127,
   author = {Chen, Quanyuan and Yao, Yuan and Li, Xinying and Lu, Jun and Zhou, Juan and Huang, Zhaolu},
   title = {Comparison of heavy metal removals from aqueous solutions by chemical precipitation and characteristics of precipitates},
   journal = {Journal of Water Process Engineering},
   volume = {26},
   pages = {289-300},
   abstract = {Typical chemical precipitation methods using lime (Ca(OH)2), soda ash (Na2CO3) and sodium sulfide (Na2S) for removals of heavy metals (i.e. Zn (II), Cu (II) and Pb (II)) from aqueous solutions were compared by jar tests. A focus was especially given to particle size differences and chemical phase conversion of precipitates. A removal of 99.99% from aqueous solutions with three precipitants was achieved for copper and zinc at an initial concentration of 100 mg/L. And lead was efficiently removed (99.75%) by sodium sulfide. In contrast, the maximal lead removals with lime or soda ash precipitation were only 76.14% and 97.78%. The mean particle size of precipitates was in the range of 55 nm–45 μm, depending on properties of precipitants and heavy metal to precipitant ratios. The settling performance of the sludge derived from precipitation was dominated by particle size and Zeta-potential of precipitates. It was observed that ultra-fine copper sulfide particles resulted from the precipitation were around 55 nm and did not settle in 12 h due to electrostatic repulsion force between particles. The main compounds in the sludge obtained from precipitation were metal hydroxides and metal sulfides. However, spontaneous dehydration of metal hydroxide, oxidation of sulfide and atmospheric carbonation were identified by means of XRD and thermal analyses, which is invaluable to the disposal and utilization of the sludge.},
   keywords = {Heavy metal
Precipitation
Sludge characteristics
Particle size
Solid–liquid separation},
   ISSN = {2214-7144},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.jwpe.2018.11.003},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jwpe.2018.11.003},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN163,
   author = {De Jesus, Kevin Lawrence M. and Senoro, Delia B. and Dela Cruz, Jennifer C. and Chan, Eduardo B.},
   title = {Neuro-Particle Swarm Optimization Based In-Situ Prediction Model for Heavy Metals Concentration in Groundwater and Surface Water},
   journal = {Toxics},
   volume = {10},
   number = {2},
   pages = {95},
   ISSN = {2305-6304},
   DOI = {10.3390/toxics10020095},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.3390/toxics10020095},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN104,
   author = {Duggal, Vikas and Rani, Asha and Mehra, Rohit and Balaram, V.},
   title = {Risk assessment of metals from groundwater in northeast Rajasthan},
   journal = {Journal of the Geological Society of India},
   volume = {90},
   number = {1},
   pages = {77-84},
   ISSN = {0016-7622},
   DOI = {10.1007/s12594-017-0666-z},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12594-017-0666-z},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN96,
   author = {Egbueri, Johnbosco C.},
   title = {Assessment of the quality of groundwaters proximal to dumpsites in Awka and Nnewi metropolises: a comparative approach},
   journal = {International Journal of Energy and Water Resources},
   volume = {2},
   number = {1-4},
   pages = {33-48},
   ISSN = {2538-3604},
   DOI = {10.1007/s42108-018-0004-1},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s42108-018-0004-1},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN255,
   author = {Findik, Ö and Aras, S.},
   title = {Application of the metal pollution indices on surface waters for assessment of environmental risk: a case study for Damsa reservoir (Cappadocia, Türkiye)},
   journal = {International Journal of Environmental Science and Technology},
   ISSN = {1735-1472},
   DOI = {10.1007/s13762-022-04102-1},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13762-022-04102-1},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN229,
   author = {Long, Xiting and Liu, Fei and Zhou, Xin and Pi, Jing and Yin, Wei and Li, Fang and Huang, Shuping and Ma, Fang},
   title = {Estimation of spatial distribution and health risk by arsenic and heavy metals in shallow groundwater around Dongting Lake plain using GIS mapping},
   journal = {Chemosphere},
   volume = {269},
   pages = {128698},
   abstract = {Potable groundwater has become the primary water source for the local population because of the serious pollution of As and heavy metals in the surface water around the Dongting Lake Plain. A comprehensive research on the shallow groundwater was performed in this study via geographical information system (GIS) and geochemical method to evaluate groundwater quality and health risks of shallow groundwater in Dongting Lake Plain. Eighty-seven samples were collected and the content of As and twelve other heavy metals (e.g., Al, Fe, Zn, Cu, Mo, Ni, Mn, Co, Ba, Pb, Cd, and Cr) in the samples were detected by inductively coupled plasma–mass spectrum (ICP-MS) technology. The water pollution situation was assessed using heavy metal contents and evaluation indices, and human health risks were evaluated on the basis of both carcinogenic and noncarcinogenic aspects. Results showed that the shallow groundwater quality is moderately to heavily contaminated and should be considered in some areas of the Li and Xiangjiang River coasts. Several regions have the potential of carcinogenic risks induced by As and the groundwater in some regions may have the risk of Cr carcinogenesis in the wet season. These findings suggested that the potential harm caused by Fe, Zn, Mn, Cr, and As pollution of groundwater, especially As and Cr in wet season, must be considered. The spatio-temporal study on the groundwater quality evaluation may be beneficial to the protection and sustainable development of groundwater resources in Dongting Lake Plain.Summary: Although the overall noncarcinogenic health risk by metals in shallow groundwater of Dongting Lake is low, noncarcinogenic health risks caused by Fe, Zn, Mn, and As exist in some areas.},
   keywords = {Dongting lake floodplain
Shallow groundwater
Arsenic
Heavy metal
GIS-Mapping},
   ISSN = {0045-6535},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.chemosphere.2020.128698},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2020.128698},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN213,
   author = {Muthukumaran, Peraman and Suresh Babu, Palanisamy and Shyamalagowri, Shanmugasundaram and Kamaraj, Murugesan and Manikandan, Arumugam and Aravind, Jeyaseelan},
   title = {Nanotechnological approaches as a promising way for heavy metal mitigation in an aqueous system},
   journal = {Journal of Basic Microbiology},
   volume = {62},
   number = {3-4},
   pages = {376-394},
   note = {Times Cited: 1
Si
PALANISAMY, SURESH BABU/AAH-4523-2019; Shanmugasundaram, Shyamalagowri/; Kamaraj, Murugesan/; Aravind, J/O-9296-2015
PALANISAMY, SURESH BABU/0000-0001-9859-2208; Shanmugasundaram, Shyamalagowri/0000-0002-4273-1253; Kamaraj, Murugesan/0000-0002-0111-8524; Aravind, J/0000-0001-9699-2312
0
1
3
5
1521-4028},
   abstract = {The ever-rising environmental problems because of heavy metals emerging from anthropogenic activities pose an impending threat to all biota globally. Considering their persistence and possibility in biomagnification, they are prominent among pollutants. There has been an apparent shift of research interest in advancing cost-effective and competent technologies to mitigate environmental contaminants, specifically heavy metals. In the recent two decades, tailored nanomaterials (NMs), nanoparticles, and NM-based adsorbents have been emerging for removing heavy metal pollution on a sustainable scale, especially the green synthesis of these nanoproducts effective and nonhazardous means. Hence, this review explores the various avenues in nanotechnology, an attempt to gauge nanotechnological approaches to mitigate heavy metals in the aqueous system, especially emphasizing the recent trends and advancements. Inputs on remediating heavy metal in sustainable and environmentally benign aspects recommended future directions to compensate for the voids in this domain have been addressed.},
   ISSN = {0233-111X},
   DOI = {10.1002/jobm.202100365},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/jobm.202100365},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN230,
   author = {Satarug, Soisungwan},
   title = {Cadmium Sources and Toxicity},
   journal = {Toxics},
   volume = {7},
   number = {2},
   pages = {25},
   ISSN = {2305-6304},
   DOI = {10.3390/toxics7020025},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.3390/toxics7020025},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN95,
   author = {Tiwari, Ashwani Kumar and Singh, Abhay Kumar and Singh, Amit Kumar and Singh, M. P.},
   title = {Hydrogeochemical analysis and evaluation of surface water quality of {Pratapgarh} district, {Uttar Pradesh}, {India}},
   journal = {Applied Water Science},
   volume = {7},
   number = {4},
   pages = {1609-1623},
   ISSN = {2190-5487},
   DOI = {10.1007/s13201-015-0313-z},
   url = {https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13201-015-0313-z},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN226,
   author = {Zhang, Shengnan and Tian, Yimei and Guo, Hao and Liu, Ran and He, Nan and Li, Zhuang and Zhao, Weigao},
   title = {Study on the occurrence of typical heavy metals in drinking water and corrosion scales in a large community in northern {China}},
   journal = {Chemosphere},
   volume = {290},
   note = {Times Cited: 0
zhao, weigao/0000-0002-4955-1626
0
22
1879-1298},
   abstract = {Excessive heavy metal content in drinking water could lead to red water and acute and chronic diseases. A field study in combination with batch experiments using pipe scales of drinking water distribution systems (DWDS) in the study area, was used to determine the content distribution and migration of As, Cd, Cr, Mn, Pb, and V in DWDS. In the field study, As, Cd, Cr, Pb, and V contents in pipe scales and drinking water were extremely low and did not exceed the Chinese drinking water standards. However, Mn concentrations at the end of the DWDS with aged and corrosive pipes were relatively high, which presented a risk of excessive release. The batch experiment showed that As in pipe scales would not be released into water under static immersion conditions; however, pipe scales would release excessive Cd, Cr, Mn, Pb, and V in the initial reaction stage, and the heavy metal contents released by tubercle scales in the initial release stage were at least twice as much as those released by loose scales. The mass percentage of four metals (excluding Cd and Pb) released from pipe scales was extremely low. The field study and batch experiment data both suggested a strong correlation between Cr and V released into the water, indicating a synergistic effect. There were differences in heavy metals released in the field research and the batch experiment. The amount of Cd, Cr, Pb, and V released were not consistent with its proportion in pipe scales. As release did not occur under static conditions, but may be promoted by the water flow in the actual network. The effect of water flow on heavy metal release in DWDS should be considered.},
   ISSN = {0045-6535},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.chemosphere.2021.133145},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2021.133145},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks in URL strings at arbitrary locations
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```